# How can I add more information to MS Dynamics 2009 AX's alert messages with X++?

Tags: axapta, x++, ax, dynamics-ax-2009

Does anyone have some sample code or can direct me to which class I can modify to add more information to the alert messages in Dynamics AX (DAX). I want to for instance add a vendor number and userid when a name of a vendor has been changed.

EDIT: I have been told by someone that HTML code must be entered in the description panel when setting up the alert. If this is true and anyone has more info on this it would be great if you could share this info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say alert messages, do you mean the popup messages when you do something in the app, or alert emails the system sends to you? From your question, it seems like the former, but from the accepted answer, it seems like the latter. :-)

Comment: Alert emails the system sends to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an article on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834423.aspx) that shows the merge-data elements you can use in an e-mail template.

To add a new merge-data element, you will need to modify the class `EventActionEmail`. The method `createEmailParameterMap` returns a map containing the elements and the data to replace them with.  The `execute` method passes that map to `SysEmailTable::sendMail` to actually format and send the email.